# Co-ordinate system imports incorrectly from SolidWorks to Meshlab

Tags: meshlab

I am trying to save an STL of a model with a defined coordinate system. I have recently reinstalled SolidWorks and Meshlab due to a hard drive error and ever since then my STL's are saving with incorrect co-ordinate systems. I have attached to images below of where i want the co-ordinate system and where it is placing it.

**SolidWorks co-ordinates**

[image: SolidWorks co-ordinates]

**Meshlabs co-ordinates**

[image: Meshlabs co-ordinates]

Could someone please advise if this might be a settings issue or any possible fixes. The part displayed is just for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate a coordinate system with your export to reorient a model. You can also do this with a macro/program. In this case, you might not even need to create a coordinate system as you can simply reorient your triangles and create STL on a fly. Please see [this example](https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/import-export/export-stl/)